# First-person perspective in master's thesis acknowledgements

Tags: thesis, masters, acknowledgement

In my institution, the acknowledgements section of a master's thesis may be quite personal so I thought I'd thank my fiancée who is (very) pregnant now, thanking her for carrying the burden of pregnancy.

However, the thesis is written by me and my colleague. The problem is obvious, how do I write a first-person perspective in the acknowledgements section where everything else is written as "we"?

Is "I, (My Name), would like to extend my gratitude and love towards (Fiancée's name), who during these months of writing has been carrying our child." peculiar and or inappropriate?

Comment: There are too many unknown factors here, such as the cultural norms in place. I'd personally leave out the pregnancy part (opinion), but it is common to thank a family member. or even a fiancée, for there continuing support.

Comment: I find it strange that a master's thesis has two authors, as opposed to each writing their own thesis focusing on their contributions to the project(s).

Comment: @JonCuster I agree with this.  In fact clear attribution in a thesis is essential so that nobody doubts the thesis is the work of the student.

Comment: @JonCuster Unusual, but perhaps not all that rare. I supervised one such Master's thesis, and I know of a joint doctoral thesis at the Harvard School of Education.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's common to see two separate acknowledgment paragraphs in the introduction to a jointly authored work.

> We owe much to many for help with ...
>
> ... professional thanks ...
>
> Ethan: My wife, Joan's ongoing contribution began 56 years ago when she
> asked me how I'd feel if I went to medical school and did no more
> mathematics.   ...
>
> Maura:  I owe a greater debt than I could ever express to my husband
> Jack Reynolds. ...